# making dropdowns dependent using "id" and "name" and Formhelper

Tags: flutter, dart

im trying to make my dropdowns in flutter dependent, but they are not. I got the List and Strings in my class. Then i gave the countries an id and a name.
The in my return SafeArea i did the same.

If within the Formhelper i change the optionvalue to either "val" or "id" (small letters) instead of "ID" in caps i get a red error right now. Interesting thing is that the country dropdown in still fine if i change the optionlabel in the second dropdown, which is city, from "Name" to "name", but cities shows the error then....
So no matter if i switch from "id" to "val" or from "id" to "ID" or similar it doesnt work.
Anybody got an idea ?

```
class _HomePageState extends State<HomePage> {

  List<dynamic> countries = [];
  List<dynamic> cities = [];
```

```
String? countryId;
String? cityId;
```

```
@override
void initState() {
  super.initState();

  countries.add({"id": 1, "name": "Belgien"});
  countries.add({"id": 2, "name": "Deutschland"});
```

```
cities = [
  {"ID": 1, "Name": "Nivelles", "ParentId": 1},


  {"ID": 1, "Name": "Augsburg", "ParentId": 2},
  {"ID": 2, "Name": "Berlin", "ParentId": 2},
```

```
@override
Widget build(BuildContext context) {

  return SafeArea(
    child: Scaffold(
      appBar: AppBar(
        title: const Text(
          "Flutter - Dependent Dropdown",
        ),
        backgroundColor: const Color(0xFF2F562E),
        centerTitle: true,
      ),
      body: Container(
        color: const Color(0x406E6C6C),
       child: Column(
        children: [
          FormHelper.dropDownWidgetWithLabel(
            context,
            "Land",
            "Selected Country",
            countryId,
            countries,
                (onChangedVal) {
              countryId = onChangedVal;
              print("Selected Country: $onChangedVal");

              cities = cities.where(
                    (stateItem) => stateItem["ParentId"].toString() == onChangedVal.toString(),
              ).toList();

            }, (onValidateVal){
            if(onValidateVal == null) {
              return 'Please Select Country';
            }
            return null;
          },
            borderColor: Theme.of(context).primaryColor,
            borderFocusColor: Theme.of(context).primaryColor,
            borderRadius: 10,
            // optionValue = "ID",
            // optionLabel = "Name",
          ),
          FormHelper.dropDownWidgetWithLabel(
            context,
            "Stadt",
            "Select City",
            cityId,
            cities,
                (onChangedVal) {
              cityId = onChangedVal;
              // ignore: avoid_print
              print("Selected State: $onChangedVal");
            },
                (onValidate) {
              return null;
            },
            borderColor: Theme.of(context).primaryColor,
            borderFocusColor: Theme.of(context).primaryColor,
            borderRadius: 10,
            optionValue: "ID",
            optionLabel: "Name",
          ),
```

Answer (score 0):

I've recently used the dropdown like this

1st step

```
List<String> listOfPromote = [
     'My biggest work achievement is',
     'An epic work fail i had was',
];
```

2nd step

```
String? promoteValue;
```

3rd step (create a DropdownButtonFormField)

```
      DropdownButtonFormField(
      decoration: InputDecoration(
        enabledBorder: UnderlineInputBorder(
          borderSide: BorderSide(
              color: Color(0xFFF44336)),
        ),
        focusedBorder: const UnderlineInputBorder(
            borderSide: BorderSide(color: Colors.grey),
        errorBorder: UnderlineInputBorder(
            borderSide: BorderSide(
                color: Color(0xFFF44336))),
      ),
      isDense: false,
      value: experienceValue,
      hint: Text(
        'Select an experience',
        style: Textstyle.copyWith(
          color: Color.withAlpha(0xFFF44336),
        ),
      ),
      onChanged: (value) {
        setState(() {
          experienceValue = value;
          //print(experienceValue);
        });
      },
      onSaved: (value) {
        setState(() {
          experienceValue = value;
        });
      },
      validator: (String? value) {
        if (value!.isEmpty) {
          return "can't empty";
        } else {
          return null;
        }
      },
      items: listOfExperience.map((String val) {
        return DropdownMenuItem(
          value: val,
          child: Text(val),
        );
      }).toList(),
    ),
  ),
```

I hope this will be helpful to understand and implement your one's.
If it's not, then comment.